# Xcode Compiles C++ Code, but Eclipse doesn't

Tags: android, c++, xcode, eclipse

I am totally and hopelessly lost here.  I've recently started trying to port my iOS app to android with Cocos2d-x, but I've run into a problem that makes me want to throw my hands up.

I'm creating a class in C++ and trying to set it's value in the game scene.  I've found Eclipse to be so clunky that I figured I would do the bulk of my coding in xcode and just use Eclipse to handle the layouts.  The problem is, my code compiles fine in Xcode, but gives me tons of errors in Eclipse.  What am I doing wrong?

### Domino.h

```
#ifndef DOMINO_H_
#define DOMINO_H_

using namespace std;

#include <string.h>

#include "cocos2d.h"

class Domino : public cocos2d::CCSprite
{
public:
    //Default Contructor
    Domino();

    //Overload Contructor
    Domino(std::string, std::string, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);

    //Deconstructor Contructor
    ~Domino();

    //Accessor Constructor
    string getstr_tilename() ;
    string getstr_mirrortilename() ;
    int getint_leading();
    int getint_trailing();
    int getint_suitrank() ;
    int getint_trickvalue() ;
    int getint_playerid() ;
    int getint_matchtile() ;
    int getint_bidvalue() ;
    int getint_markvalue() ;

    //Mutator Function
    void setstr_tilename(string) ;
    void setstr_mirrortilename(string) ;
    void setint_leading(int);
    void setint_trailing(int);
    void setint_suitrank(int) ;
    void setint_trickvalue(int) ;
    void setint_playerid(int) ;
    void setint_matchtile(int) ;
    void setint_bidvalue(int) ;
    void setint_markvalue(int) ;

private:
    int _int_leading;
    int _int_trailing;
    int _int_suitrank;
    int _int_trickvalue;
    int _int_playerid;
    int _int_matchtile;
    int _int_bidvalue;
    int _int_markvalue;

    std::string _str_tilename;
    std::string _str_mirrortilename;
};


#endif /* DOMINO_H_ */
```

### Domino.cpp

```
#include "Domino.h"

Domino::Domino()
{

    _str_tilename="";
    _str_mirrortilename="";

    _int_leading=0;
    _int_trailing=0;
    _int_suitrank=0;
    _int_trickvalue=0;
    _int_playerid=0;
    _int_matchtile=0;
    _int_bidvalue=0;
    _int_markvalue=0;
}


Domino::Domino(string str_tilename,  string str_mirrortilename,  int int_leading, int int_trailing, int int_suitrank, int int_trickvalue, int int_playerid, int int_matchtile, int int_bidvalue, int int_markvalue)
{

    _str_tilename=str_tilename;
    _str_mirrortilename=str_mirrortilename;

    _int_leading=int_leading;
    _int_trailing=int_trailing;
    _int_suitrank=int_suitrank;
    _int_trickvalue=int_trickvalue;
    _int_playerid=int_playerid;
    _int_matchtile=int_matchtile;
    _int_bidvalue=int_bidvalue;
    _int_markvalue=int_markvalue;


}

Domino::~Domino()
{


}

//===============================Getters======================================
string Domino::getstr_tilename()
{
    return _str_tilename;

}

string Domino::getstr_mirrortilename()
{
    return _str_mirrortilename;

}

int Domino::getint_leading()
{
    return _int_leading;

}

int Domino::getint_trailing()
{
    return _int_trailing;

}

int Domino::getint_suitrank()
{
    return _int_suitrank;

}


int Domino::getint_trickvalue()
{
    return _int_trickvalue;

}

int Domino::getint_playerid()
{
    return _int_playerid;

}

int Domino::getint_matchtile()
{
    return _int_matchtile;

}

int Domino::getint_bidvalue()
{
    return _int_bidvalue;

}

int Domino::getint_markvalue()
{
    return _int_markvalue;

}

//===============================Setters======================================

void Domino::setstr_tilename(string str_tilename)
{
    _str_tilename=str_tilename;

}

void Domino::setstr_mirrortilename(string str_mirrortilename)
{
    _str_mirrortilename=str_mirrortilename;

}

void Domino::setint_leading(int int_leading)
{
   _int_leading=int_leading;

}

void Domino::setint_trailing(int int_trailing)
{
    _int_trailing=int_trailing;

}

void Domino::setint_suitrank(int int_suitrank)
{
    _int_suitrank=int_suitrank;

}


void Domino::setint_trickvalue(int int_trickvalue)
{
    _int_trickvalue=int_trickvalue;

}

void Domino::setint_playerid(int int_playerid)
{
    _int_playerid=int_playerid;

}

void Domino::setint_matchtile(int int_matchtile)
{
    _int_matchtile=int_matchtile;

}

void Domino::setint_bidvalue(int int_bidvalue)
{
    _int_bidvalue=int_bidvalue;

}

void Domino::setint_markvalue(int int_markvalue)
{
    _int_markvalue=int_markvalue;

}
```

### GameScene.cpp

```
Domino d00;
d00.initWithSpriteFrameName("blank.png");
d00.setstr_tilename("0-0.png");
d00.setstr_mirrortilename("0-0.png");
d00.setint_leading(0);
d00.setint_trailing(0);
d00.setint_bidvalue(3);
d00.setint_matchtile(0);
```

In Xcode, it builds just fine and even shows the game scene in iphone simulator.

In Eclipse, I get an "Undefined reference to Domino::Domino" error when I try to create this object.  Subsequent messages are of the "undefined reference to `Domino::setstr_tilename(std::basic_string, std::allocator >)" variety.

What do I need to do to get this working in BOTH IDEs?

Comment: It sounds like Domino.cpp is not compiled and linked into your executable.

Comment: Eclipse is a Java IDE, but it is C++ capable.

Comment: Brian was right.  Once again, I forgot to add the class to my .mk file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a project of cocos2d-x for android and replace the files. cpp and. h the end build the project...

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_build_and_run_HelloWorld_on_Android_NDK_r5_and_above